# 401 Unauthorized when use Content Management API of Episerver

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I'm consider to use Content Management API for getting and updating content with Content Guid. I just want to build a simple project following the optimizely official guide
https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-management-system/v1.6.0-content-management-api/docs/configuring-the-api

I don't need to secure the request with authentication when call API so I config startup.cs simply as below:

```
            services.AddContentManagementApi(options =>
            {
                options.DisableScopeValidation = true;
            });
            services.ConfigureContentApiOptions(options =>
            {
                options.FlattenPropertyModel = true;
            });
```

When I'm debugging, I call ContentManagementAPI with GET method, it always returns 401 Unauthorized

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1",
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Forbidden",
    "instance": "/api/episerver/v3.0/contentmanagement/BBC1BEFD-D20D-4C6C-B565-B9D682C9E0B7",
    "traceId": "00-e9869e94a05f7ae54246b0fdec453758-712650af9e9af76f-00"
}
```

I tried with ContentDeliveryAPI when exposed GET request, it worked well when I could get the content returned. But I want to update or insert the content too, so I consider to use ContentManagementAPI

The optimizely official guide is not really clearly for me so anyone can help me to configure the Content Management API or any simple tutorial?
Thank you guys so much

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look with dotPeek what's going on, and looks like it is something that will never work for an Anonymous visitor; not sure if this is a bug or an intended behavior though.

`EPiServer.ContentManagementApi.Internal.ContentManagementController` is a controller which handles GET.

It is written in such a way that it can return Draft of a content, so it checks if a visitor has necessary permissions to work with Drafts in class `EPiServer.ContentApi.Core.Internal.UserService`, methods `IsUserAllowedToAccessDraftContent` and then `HasMoreThanReadAccess`.

Those methods check that a visitor has Read access (Anonymous visitor does have it for published pages), and also if they have "any other accesses" (which Anonymous visitor doesn't).

So I see possible ways to proceed here:

- Login as a CMS user, and then use Content Management API; disabling scope validation helps you to don't care about anything else.
- Register your custom `UserService` inheritor in the IoC container, and implement your own permissions check logic. That will affect all the Content Management API methods, but if our intention to ignore access check anyway - why not?
- Try reporting a bug to Optimizely.